# How to write a function to get the content between two lines in vim, like plug#begin() and plug#end()?

Tags: vim

For instance, how can I write a minimal function to get the content of lines between `call plug#begin()` and `call plug#end()`. vim-plug or vundle now is too complicated for me to find the related complement.

```
call plug#begin()

Plug 'foo1'
Plug 'foo2' 

call plug#end()
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @romainl I have tried to find the related functions in [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/blob/master/plug.vim), but failed. I cannot get this. `call plug#begin()` is just an example. What I want is to get the content between the specific lines.

Comment: You didn't find it because that's not how vim-plug works. Anyway, for consuming lines, see `:help getline()`.

Comment: @romainl Maybe I have a indistinct expression. vim-plug has to get these content to deal  with them, which is only a tiny part of it. And I only want to get the right point, not how vim-plug works. Anyway, thanks for your comment.

Comment: Also asked at: http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/10412/51

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to what you believe, the plugin does not "get" these configuration lines from your `~/.vimrc`. Instead, Vim invokes the plugin for each line, as `Plug` is a *custom command* provided by the vim-plug plugin manager; it gets passed the arguments (e.g. `foo1`) automatically. That's clean and nice, and no explicit retrieval or parsing is necessary. (So, you can even write `execute 'Plug' 'foo' . s:count`, and it would still work.)

The wrapping with `call plug#begin()` and `call plug#end()` is (presumably) done for:

- bootstrapping; because in your `.vimrc` plugins aren't yet loaded, and the `:Plug` command would be undefined without explicitly defining it up front
- concluding the processing; plugin managers go over all configured plugins and add them to the `'runtimepath'`; it might be more efficient to first just collect them all, and do the processing once at the end

#### On obtaining lines

This can be done via `:help :range`, combined with `:yank`:

```
/^call plug#begin()$/+1;/^call plug#end()$/-1 yank
```

---

Or, you can use more low-level functions: Find the delimiting lines via `:let startLnum = search('^call plug#begin()$', '')`, then grab the lines in between via `let lines = getline(startLnum, endLnum)`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. After reading [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/blob/master/plug.vim) again, I have already known that the formal idea is absolutely on the wrong way, it is to **define command** Plug that matters, not how to get these lines. Thanks again.